# GPIO signals from Raspberry, read by Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, signal, gpio

I'm working on a program on Arduino to control the Raspberry. My plan is using a button to make Raspberry Pi 4 switch on by pressed button (if i pressed a button for 3 seconds, raspberry will switch on). I want to use a Python script and use GPIO's to send status signals to Arduino, but when I was reading the GPIO signal from Raspberry on Serial Monitor on Arduino I have been able to see this:

[image]

A 0 and 1 party, how can i use a 0 or 1 stable signal from Raspberry? GPIO is imposible?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't follow. How will the Pi send signals to the Arduino if it is not even on?

Comment: And it seems the state of the pin is not defined and is HighZ.

Comment: Once Raspberry is switch on,  it send a signal to Arduino (to take the control of a led). That pin is used as High, declare on config.txt.

Comment: I have found the problem, the GND wasn't connected between them. Thank you so much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is useful for someone: Important note, it is neccesary the GND of both devices been connected between then, that was my mistake.